# jQuery UI Sortable - Update event called twice sorting item from connected lists

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have multiple UI sortable lists. The problem I'm running into is that when I sort an item from list A to list B, the update function get's triggered twice. I think it is because it is updating the position and updating the list.

Anyway, to handle sortable items from a connectedList I am using the receive function. All my logic related to handling a new item in the list is placed there.

I want to use the update function for handling sorting within the same list.

```
$scope.sortableEpics = {
        connectWith : '.sortableEpics',
        items : '.expanded-epic',
//      tolerance : 'pointer',
        helper : 'clone',
        axis: 'y',
        delay: 200,
        start : function(e, ui){
            previousGoal = $(e.target).attr("data-goal-id"); // On sortStart, set previousGoal to compare on sortUpdate if sortable item has moved lists
            $scope.draggingEpic = true; // If draggingEpic is true, stacked epics become 'droppable/draggable'
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        stop : function(e, ui){
            $scope.draggingEpic = false; // If draggingEpic is false, prevent dragging of stacked epics
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        update : function(e, ui){
            currentGoal = $(e.target).attr("data-goal-id");
            if(ui.sender) return; 
            if(currentGoal !== previousGoal) return; // Only execute following code if sortable is dropped within the same list

            /* Logic for a new position in the list goes here */
        },
        receive : function(e,ui){
            /* Logic for receiving a new item to the list goes here */
        }
    };
```

The problem here is that the first call to the update function does NOT have the new goal_id attached to it, so currentGoal === previousGoal always in the first call.

In the second call it's updated, and the comparison to return from the function works.

What I want is the first call to the update function to be prevented, I've tried inspecting the event and ui object, but they seem identical when drag and dropping within the same list.

How do I detect within the first call to the update function that the sortable item has moved lists and prevent further executing of the function?

Comment: Could you add a simple fiddle for your code?

Comment: @AliSoltani I've solved the problem, still thanks ! The solutation was to Set currentList in over function and startList in start function, compare both in update function